# compare two dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, compare

How to compare two dimensional array with different size (different row and column)?

I have two different matrix like this : `kuliahprior[][]` and `hasil1[][]`.

I want to see if there is element of `kuliahprior` in `hasil1`, they have different size. 
I make the check process in `cekKondisi()` method. And then call it in `cekpriorfinal()` method, by sent element of `hasil1[i][j]`. This is my code.

But they still hang.. not error just hang for unknown (sorry for my english, thankyou)

```
    public String cekKondisi(int kdbuka){
        String status = " ";
        String kd_dosen; String kdbukax[] = new String[MAX]; 
        for (int i=0; i<dosenprior.length;i++){    
             kd_dosen=dosenprior[i];
             kdbukax=peta.getKodeBuka1(kd_dosen,tahunakademik);
             for (int k=0;k<kdbukax.length;k++){
                if (kdbuka==Integer.parseInt(kuliahprior[i][k]))
                   status = slotprior[i];      
            }
        }    
        return status;
    }


    public void cekpriorfinal(){
        String status [][]=new String[15][15];
        for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<15;j++){
               status [i][j] = cekKondisi(hasil1[i][j]);     
            }
        }   
        for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<15;j++){
                if (status[i][j]==" ")
                    status[i][j]="ok";
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<15;i++){
             for (int j=0;j<15;j++){
                System.out.print (status[i][j]+" "); 
             }
             System.out.println();    
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't spot anything that causes an infinite loop, so I would suggest to check if this line doesn't cause the hang:

```
kdbukax = peta.getKodeBuka1(kd_dosen,tahunakademik);
```

Make sure you are not impatient and it was still working on the result.

You might try to use a debugger and pause the application at a random point where you think it "hangs". You will see at which line it currently was. Try to solve the problem somewhere there or in that context.

Also, change this

```
String kdbukax[] = new String[MAX];
```

to this:

```
String kdbukax[] = null;
```

There is no need to create an array, since you reassign the variable here:

```
kdbukax=peta.getKodeBuka1(kd_dosen,tahunakademik);
```

And if `MAX` is really big, that might take some time to allocate an array of that size. Creating an array on the heap has this complexity: `O(n)`.

Comment: dont you think it's like 4 nested loop.. is that impossible?